# Missing required architecture arm64 in file Telerik

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, telerik

I have downloaded Telerik's IOS UI trial and opened its example project in it. It runs properly on simulator but when I want to run on the real device it gives me error.

> Ld
>   /Users/gg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TelerikUIExamples-fsncxcpsvysvphgxrqnhuzcltumd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TelerikUIExamples.app/TelerikUIExamples
>   normal arm64
>       cd "/Users/gg/Documents/Telerik/UI for iOS Q2 2014/TelerikUIExamples"
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk
>   -L/Users/gg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TelerikUIExamples-fsncxcpsvysvphgxrqnhuzcltumd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/gg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TelerikUIExamples-fsncxcpsvysvphgxrqnhuzcltumd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F. -FTelerikUIExamples -FTelerikUIExamples/Images.xcassets -FTelerikUIExamples/Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset -FTelerikUIExamples/Images.xcassets/calendar_cell.imageset -FTelerikUIExamples/Images.xcassets/calendar_current_cell.imageset -FTelerikUIExamples/Images.xcassets/calendar_header.imageset -FTelerikUIExamples/Images.xcassets/calendar_selected_cell.imageset -FTelerikUIExamples/Images.xcassets/LaunchImage.launchimage -FTelerikUIExamples/Images.xcassets/logo.imageset -FTelerikUIExamples/Images.xcassets/menu.imageset -FTelerikUIExamples/Images.xcassets/pattern1.imageset -filelist /Users/gg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TelerikUIExamples-fsncxcpsvysvphgxrqnhuzcltumd/Build/Intermediates/TelerikUIExamples.build/Debug-iphoneos/TelerikUIExamples.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TelerikUIExamples.LinkFileList
>   -dead_strip -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -framework SystemConfiguration -lsqlite3.0 -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework TelerikUI -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/gg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TelerikUIExamples-fsncxcpsvysvphgxrqnhuzcltumd/Build/Intermediates/TelerikUIExamples.build/Debug-iphoneos/TelerikUIExamples.build/Objects-normal/arm64/TelerikUIExamples_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/gg/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/TelerikUIExamples-fsncxcpsvysvphgxrqnhuzcltumd/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TelerikUIExamples.app/TelerikUIExamples
>
> ld: warning: ignoring file ./TelerikUI.framework/TelerikUI, missing
>   required architecture arm64 in file ./TelerikUI.framework/TelerikUI (3
>   slices) Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TKChartPaletteItem", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Customize.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TKLinearGradientFill", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in Customize.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TKChartOhlcSeries", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FinancialChart.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TKChartCandlestickSeries", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in IndicatorsViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in FinancialChart.o
>   ..
>   .. and so on

Comment: Which device are you trying to run this on?

Comment: Can you find arm64 in Architectures under build settings?